# How to run phantomjs testcases on a remote server from jenkins

Tags: php, php-phantomjs

I have a jenkins job that has to run phantomjs on a remote server. (basically test the code on a staging server). How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Create master slave configuration in jenkins with the remote server as slave ,install phantomjs in the remote server and execute , you may use copy to master or slave plugin if you require to transfer file or use scp .
Phantom js often gives proxy errors as there are some issues watch for the correct versions.